# problem with express api not working with jwt

Tags: mern

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Spb1G.png)i am building a project which uses jwt to verify user once sign in is done but due to some reason

1. my cookie returns undefined in my main project file(ps i am using cookieParser)
   2)i recreated the project in separate folder now jwt works but the api doesnot work it returns eroor instead of giving me the result it worked, even though in my cookie segment and console logs the cookie is looged in
2. i tested it with a html file using the fecth api and in browser it works am i doing some thing wrong
   i am using vite(react frontend) and express backend any solutions really struggling with this one[code[browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFXVH.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koD7L.png)

i am just expecting the solution to this problem am a begineer

Comment: So I figured the error out today, it turns out my code is correct error was with thunderclient, i tried same code with postman and it works, still cant figure out the reason appreciate it if someone can guide.